# Material Design 2 Tabs aligned at bottom

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I want to have tabs aligned at the bottom of the **md-tab-group**, like shown below:

[image]

It is possible in Material 1 using **md-tabs-align="bottom"**. Is there anything available in Material 2 for this purpose?

Here is my code:

```
<md-tab-group> 
    <md-tab label="Tab One"> 
        Tab One Contents 
    </md-tab> 
    <md-tab label="Tab Two"> 
        Tab Two Contents 
    </md-tab> 
</md-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For whomever may stumble across this question.

[The Tabs section of the component demo site references the following in the API Reference section](https://material.angular.io/components/component/tabs)

```
@Input()            | Position of the tab header.
headerPosition      |
```

[After looking through the source I found the following:](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tabs/tab-header.ts)

```
/** Possible positions for the tab header. */
export type MdTabHeaderPosition = 'above' | 'below';
```

Thus, the following worked for me

```
<md-tab-group headerPosition="below"> 
<md-tab label="Tab One"> 
    Tab One Contents 
</md-tab> 
<md-tab label="Tab Two"> 
    Tab Two Contents 
</md-tab> 
</md-tab-group>
```

Comment: Yeah this was implemented after I opened a feature request on github. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2387

Comment: Posting this comment to emphasize your explanation of how you found the solution. I suggest more people do this as it helps us all find solutions faster!

Answer (score 2):

Think outside the box. Flip the UI upside down and then flip the content back right-side up.

```
md-tab-group{
    display:flex;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    .mat-tab-labels{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        justify-content:space-around;
        & > div{
            flex: 1;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
    }
    md-tab-body{
        transform:rotate(180deg);
        padding:20px;
    }
}

.mat-tab-body-wrapper{
    flex:1;
}
```

Comment: This will also align the tabs to space across the entire bottom of the UI. Perfect for if you're building a mobile interface.

Comment: Great ! But the feature is already available in material now :)

Answer (score 1):

See the part about properties within the [design document for md-tabs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1djxF6AKGijZl6LOoJ0asFbkf1-GqSAp1CSIyurtKVog/preview):

> **Properties**
>
> These properties can be applied to any of the root tab component tags:
>   md-tab-group, md-router-tabs, md-tab-bar, md-tab-outlet
>
> `[barPosition]` - `string` - Tells the tabs component where to
>   position the tab header - Options: `top`, `bottom`
>
> `[alignTabs]` -
>   `string` - Tells the tabs component how to align tabs - Options:
>   `start`, `end`, `center`, `stretch`

**Edit #1**

Indeed, it does not work. I got the same error with `[barPosition]="bottom"`. In addition, the accordant [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/tabs) only lists one property: `selectedIndex`. Therefore I think, that there is no easy or built-in way to place the tabs at the bottom.

**Edit #2**

You do not use Ionic 2, do you? If yes, maybe [this](http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-place-ionic-2-tabs-at-the-bottom-or-top-of-the-screen/) helps.

Comment: I have tried using [barPosition]="bottom" and I get the following error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'barPosition' since it isn't a known property of 'md-tab-group'.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. No I am not using Ionic. I will try to find a solution and also post it here if I am successful.