# How to move material ui tabs below my content and have the content expand to full height?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2

I am using tabs from Material UI tabs (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview). How do I make it so that my tabs are below the content area?

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="Tab 1">
        Content
    </md-tab>            
    <md-tab label="Tab 2">
        Content
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

I tried putting the following on `md-tab-group`, but it appeared to have to effect:

```
md-tabs-align="bottom"
```

I would also like the tab content to fill up the entire div instead of just being sized to the small amount of text I have.

Comment: AFAIK there's no *input* called "align" in [**md-tab**](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api). See if *position* property is what you're looking for.

Comment: it may not be in the documentation, but according to this, it looks like there should be a way to align to the bottom https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5432, though it is not working for me.

Comment: It's related to Material (1) not Material2.

Comment: See if [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41301877/4911842) helps.

Comment: md-align-tabs="bottom" works with material design for angular js. For Material 2 you need to use headerPosition="below".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material Design 2 Tabs aligned at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301877/material-design-2-tabs-aligned-at-bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily using `CSS3` `flex-box`.

```
mat-tab-group{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
        -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

[Check the image](http://prntscr.com/ie22s6)

Comment: This worked for another problem i had related to Material UI. But apparently I don't think this works for what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is, i believe, a better solution which uses built-in Inputs:

[Material Design 2 Tabs aligned at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301877/material-design-2-tabs-aligned-at-)
bottom

--- From that link ---

The Tabs section of the component demo site references the following in the API Reference section

```
@Input()            | Position of the tab header.
headerPosition      |
```

After looking through the source I found the following:

```
/** Possible positions for the tab header. */
export type MdTabHeaderPosition = 'above' | 'below';
```

Thus, the following worked for me

```
<md-tab-group headerPosition="below"> 
  <md-tab label="Tab One"> 
     Tab One Contents 
  </md-tab> 
  <md-tab label="Tab Two"> 
    Tab Two Contents 
  </md-tab> 
</md-tab-group>
```